# What type to use to pass FileUpload data to a class

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I am createing a stand alone class file that will handle the file uploads of my website so any page can call it with out me having to rewrite the code over and over but I am not sure what object type to pass into the function that I build in my stand alone class so it will be passed the file or files (i am allowing mutlifile uploads) that the user choses to upload. Can anyone help me out? I am building a Web Forms asp.Net 4.5 web application.

Code in current FuleUploader.cs which will not build due to "httpPostedFile could not be found" error. The FileUploader.cs file is part of a Class Libary project that builds into my web applicaiton

```
using System;
```

using System.Web;

namespace FFInfo.Classes
{
    public class FileUploader
    {

```
    public void UploadFile(HttpPostedFile File)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a `Stream`, `byte[]` or `HttpPostedFile` object. You can now call your method multiple times for multiple uploads

```
public void UploadFile(HttpPostedFile myFile)
{
   myFile.SaveAs(....); //Save to location
}
```

Usage

```
myFileUploader.UploadFile(postedFiles[i]);
```

Bytes and Streams should work anywhere - Windows, Console or Web

Comment: I tried the HttpPostedFile but it was not a reconized type. What using statment do I need to make sure to have on the page?

Comment: You need to reference `System.Web` - Add References

Comment: I thought I did, I will have to double check my code when I get home from work. Thanks.

Comment: I was right in thinking that I did include web.config and VS will not build the class file saying "HttpPostedFile count not be found" I mofidied my first post with the code that is causing this error. I should know that the class is inside a "Class Libary" project that builds into my Web Application. I do not know if this is the cause (probibily is) and now to deal with it.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. The Class Library projects dont have a refreance to the need System.Web. I added that refreance and it is working now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question, so here's a pretty general answer:

If you're working with files of unknown types, use `byte[]` to represent the file data.  After all, every file consists of bytes, so that's the best common representation you can use.  It also allows you to work with most relevant classes, such as System.IO.File.